# What is the bigger datatype than double in Java?

Tags: java, android, double, range, calculator

I am developing an android app, A Calculator. 
I have used double to save the operands. 
As a calculator calculates bigger number, it's not showing the answer properly.
For Example, If I enters 1234567890 * 1, it shows me the result 1234567936.
I think it is due to the range issues of double.
How to solve it? Help!

This is a part of the actual code containing operator's functioning:

```
bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Add Button
                                                                // Listener

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (Switch == true) {
                        display.setText(display.getText() + "");
                        op1 += Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        check = 'a';
                        display.setText(" ");
                        display2.setText("+");
                    } else if (display.getText().toString() != " "
                            && Switch == false) {
                        display.setText(display.getText() + "");
                        op1 = Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        check = 'a';
                        Switch = true;
                        display.setText(" ");
                        display2.setText("+");
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    display.setText(" ");
                }

            }
        });
        bSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Subtract
                                                                // Button
                                                                // Listener

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (Switch == true) {
                        display.setText(display.getText() + "");
                        op1 -= Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        check = 's';
                        display.setText(" ");
                        display2.setText("-");
                    } else if (display.getText().toString() != " "
                            && Switch == false) {
                        display.setText(display.getText() + "");
                        op1 = Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        check = 's';
                        Switch = true;
                        display.setText(" ");
                        display2.setText("-");
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    display.setText(" ");
                }

            }
        });
        bMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Multiply
                                                                // Button
                                                                // Listener

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (Switch == true) {
                        display.setText(display.getText() + "");
                        op1 *= Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        check = 'm';
                        display.setText(" ");
                        display2.setText("x");
                    } else if (display.getText().toString() != " "
                            && Switch == false) {
                        display.setText(display.getText() + "");
                        op1 = Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        check = 'm';
                        Switch = true;
                        display.setText(" ");
                        display2.setText("x");
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    display.setText(" ");
                }

            }
        });
        bDiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Divide
                                                                // Button
                                                                // Listener

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (Switch == true) {
                        display.setText(display.getText() + "");
                        op1 /= Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        check = 'd';
                        display.setText(" ");
                        display2.setText("/");
                    } else if (display.getText().toString() != " "
                            && Switch == false) {
                        display.setText(display.getText() + "");
                        op1 = Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        check = 'd';
                        Switch = true;
                        display.setText(" ");
                        display2.setText("/");
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    display.setText(" ");
                }

            }
        });
```

This a part of actual code containing equal's to functioning:

```
bEq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Equals To
                                                            // Button
                                                            // Listener

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (display.getText().toString() != " ") {
                        double result;
                        int temp = 0;
                        op2 = Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                        op1 = Math.floor(op1 * 100) / 100;
                        op2 = Math.floor(op2 * 100) / 100;
                        if (check == 'a') {
                            result = op1 + op2;
                            temp = (int) result;
                            if (result - temp == 0) {
                                display.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
                            } else {
                                display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                            }
                        } else if (check == 's') {
                            result = op1 - op2;
                            temp = (int) result;
                            if (result - temp == 0) {
                                display.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
                            } else {
                                display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                            }
                        } else if (check == 'm') {
                            result = op1 * op2;
                            temp = (int) result;
                            if (result - temp == 0) {
                                display.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
                            } else {
                                display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                            }
                        } else if (check == 'd') {
                            if (op2 != 0) {
                                result = op1 / op2;
                                temp = (int) result;
                                if (result - temp == 0) {
                                    display.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
                                } else {
                                    display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                                }
                            } else {
                                display.setText(" ");
                                display2.setText("Invalid");
                            }
                        } else if (check == 'p') {

                            try {
                                if (op2 == 0) {
                                    throw new Exception();
                                } else {
                                    result = (op1 / op2) * 100;
                                    temp = (int) result;
                                    if (result - temp == 0) {
                                        display.setText(String
                                                .valueOf(temp) + "%");
                                    } else {
                                        display.setText(String
                                                .valueOf(result) + "%");
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                display.setText(" ");
                                display2.setText("Invalid");
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        display.setText(" ");
                    }
                    Switch = false;
                    check = '\0';
                    display2.setText("=");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    display.setText(" ");
                }

            }
        });
    } finally {
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: Why are you using `Float.valueOf(...)`?  The `float` data type is limited to something like six digits of precision.  Do yourself a favor and never, ever use `float`.  (Just don't, OK?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you really need big numbers. The one you gave in your example, though, should fit into even a humble `int`, so there's probably something wrong with your code.

Comment: It is calculating using simple multiplication code:
result = op1 * op2;

Secondly, It is also showing unexpected results with other operators like: 
987654321 + 1 = 987654337

For smaller operands, the result is correct like:
9999999 * 1 = 9999999

Comment: I'd like to believe you, but from what you've said about the behavior it produces, I can't. You'll need to post your actual code if you want further help in debugging your program.

Comment: @KushGrover In that code, you're using `Float.valueOf`, so you're getting a `float` value. `float` is *not* precise enough to hold those values.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: @KushGrover Exactly what I said in my answer. Use `int` or `double` or `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`. All of those are big enough to hold the numbers you mentioned. Just do a little bit of research into the limitations of precision of `int` and `double` and you'll be on your way.

Comment: Changing Float.valueOf to Double.valueOf solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

`BigInteger` is solution to this problem. And there is no theoretical limit.